# Play WEBM music on Debian headless

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi, arm, mplayer

I'm able to play .mp3, .ogg, .m4a, etc., but .webm does not work. The error I get is:

```
Playing La Caution-Thé à la Menthe Instrumentale.webm.
[mkv] Unknown/unsupported audio codec ID 'A_OPUS' for track 1 or missing/faulty
[mkv] private codec data.
[mkv] Track ID 1: audio (A_OPUS), -aid 0, -alang eng
[mkv] No video track found/wanted.
Detected file format: Matroska
No stream found.


Exiting... (End of file)
```

I'm running it on a Raspberry PI (2, I think):

```
Linux host 4.9.35-v7+ #1014 SMP Fri Jun 30 14:47:43 BST 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Am I missing some library? When running it through `mplayer.exe` under Windows it works just fine and `avconv` is able to convert in the Raspberry PI too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch to `mpv` instead of `mplayer`. Problem instantly solved!

Comment: `cvlc` can play it as well.